# Unable to get VM debian machine work with K80

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nvidia

I create a deep learning VM to run a project using some custom tensorflow models and google vision api, google nlu api.
I set up a machine with Debian10 and tensorflow 2.4(cuda11) and I choose 1 nvidia K80 GPU. I installed cuda11 using this [link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Debian&target_version=10&target_type=debnetwork). when I run nvidia-smi, I get this famous ugly message:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I try to install cuda10 or any other but it does not exist for debian at all: see this [cuda 10](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64)

How to resolve this problem, please!

Comment: Did you try this? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/create-vm-with-gpus#install-driver-manual

Comment: I have used Deep learning VM, but it does not install the CUDA drivers. It just contains tensorflow 2.4. So, I have to manage everything myself which does not make any sense. waste of time and money! I

Comment: Please use 'runfile (local)' to install and give a try

Comment: Able to create deep learning VM using glcoud command:
export IMAGE_FAMILY="tf2-2-4-cu110"
export ZONE="us-west1-b"
export INSTANCE_NAME="my-new-instance1"
export INSTANCE_TYPE="n1-standard-8"
gcloud compute instances create $INSTANCE_NAME \
        --zone=$ZONE \
        --image-family=$IMAGE_FAMILY \
        --image-project=deeplearning-platform-release \
        --maintenance-policy=TERMINATE \
        --accelerator="type=nvidia-tesla-k80,count=1" \
        --machine-type=$INSTANCE_TYPE \
        --boot-disk-size=120GB \
        --metadata="install-nvidia-driver=True"

Comment: Here is the nvidia-smi output:
Thu Jan  7 18:18:36 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 396.44                 Driver Version: 396.44                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce this error in my own project.
I have installed a VM Instance with the following characteristics:

- Machine type: n1-standard-1
- GPUs: 1 x NVIDIA Tesla K80
- Boot disk: debian-10-buster-v20201216

As you mentioned in your post there are no drivers for Linux: CUDA Toolkit 10, So I used the steps described in this [link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Debian&target_version=10&target_type=deblocal) to install it, I had some complications to install the drivers and at the end I was able to reproduce your issue and I got the following message after the installation:

```
$ sudo nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I tried again, but now I changed my installation a little bit:

- Machine type: n1-standard-1
- GPUs: 1 x NVIDIA Tesla K80
- Boot disk: c0-common-gce-gpu-image-20200128

The boot disk I used this time `c0-common-gce-gpu-image-20200128` is a GPU Optimized Debian image , m32 (with CUDA 10.0), A Debian 9 based image with CUDA/CuDNN/NCCL pre-installed

When I accessed to this instance through ssh the first time I received the following question:

```
This VM requires Nvidia drivers to function correctly.   Installation takes ~1 minute.
Would you like to install the Nvidia driver? [y/n] y
Installing Nvidia driver.
```

And it automatically installed the drivers.

```
$ sudo nvidia-smi
Thu Jan  7 19:08:06 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.104      Driver Version: 410.104      CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   75C    P0    91W / 149W |      0MiB / 11441MiB |    100%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I also tried with a TensorFlow image as you mentioned that you are using TensorFlow: c0-deeplearning-tf-1-15-cu110-v20201229-debian-10
That according to the information of this image, it is a Deep Learning Image: TensorFlow 1.15, m61 CUDA 110, A debian-10 Linux based image with TensorFlow 1.15 (With CUDA 110 and Intel(TM) MKL-DNN, Intel® MKL) plus Intel(TM)optimized NumPy, SciPy, and scikit-learn.
In this case I [verified the TensorFlow installation too](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#verify-your-installation):

```
$ python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
2021-01-07 20:29:02.854218: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
Tensor("Sum:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

And it works well.

Hence, there seems to be a problem between the image installed (Devian 10) and the CUDA Toolkit needed for the GPU type (NVIDIA K80).

My suggestion here is to use a Deep Learning VM image, You could see the the full list at this link: [Choosing an image](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/images)

Comment: Thanks. I have already created a new one and It is working fine!